# How to embed literal <code> snippet within React/JSX component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, and I'm trying to render a static CSS code sample within a React component, like this:

```
React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <code> body { color: blue; } </code>
    )
  }
});
```

However, this does not seem to work.

Is there some special way for me to escape code like this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `<code>{"body { color: blue; }"}</code>`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo This does the trick, but I lose syntax highlighting for the portion in quotes. I don't suppose you are aware of an alternative in which syntax highlighting is preserved?

Comment: @AustinYork - As the suggestion is to put the content in a string literal, I'd be very surprised if any editor intentionally continued to syntax highlight the contents (as many devs wouldn't want that normally).

Comment: In WebStorm you can Alt-Enter -> Inject Language and choose the language for the string if you like.  But it's not something most editors support.  It's not code, it's a text string that happens to include code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@ColonelThirtyTwo's answer does the trick:

```
<code>{"body { color: blue; }"}</code>
```

Answer (score 8):

It is probably also worth noting that this can be done with multiline strings too:

```
<code>{`
  html { background: red; }
  body { color: blue; }
`}</code>
```

Comment: Thats nice, because it's easy to pass parameters if needed, using ${myparam}

Comment: This works. Thanks for that! I needed to wrap this with <pre> tag to preserve the next line and original formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do multiline you have to add line breaks  as follows. If you don't they will all be on the same line.

```
    <code>
      {`html { background: red; }`}<br/>
      {`body { color: blue; }`}<br/>
    </code>
```